# Ошибка QT. Программа по шаблону из документации

Tags: c++, qt, функции, объявление

Разбираю [пример](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/widgets-groupbox-window-cpp.html) из документации Qt 4.7 (Пишу на 4.8), интересует функция createFirstGroup

Попробовал немного изменить ее, чтобы реализовать такой интерфейс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Редактор кода выдает такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите исправить. Реализация моей функции

```
QGroupBox MainClass::createFirstGroup(){
QGroupBox *groupFontBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Параметры"));
QSpinBox *FontsizeSpin = new QSpinBox (this);
FontsizeSpin->setRange(6, 72);
FontsizeSpin->setSuffix(" пт");

QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout;

QLabel *FLabel = new QLabel (this);
FLabel->setText("Шрифт");

vbox ->addWidget(FLabel);
vbox ->addWidget(FontsizeSpin);
groupFontBox->setLayout(vbox);

return groupFontBox;
}
```

Comment: Дольше и сложнее было задать вопрос на SO (со всеми этими скриншотами), чем внимательно посмотреть на вывод об ошибке (одной!) в редакторе )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У функции тип возвращаемого значения `QGroupBox`

```
QGroupBox MainClass::createFirstGroup(){
^^^^^^^^^
```

, однако из функции вы возвращаете объект

```
return groupFontBox;
```

имеющий тип `QGroupBox *`, то есть указатель на объект типа `QGroupBox`.

```
QGroupBox *groupFontBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Параметры"));
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому компилятор выдает сообщение о том, что он не способен преобразовать скалярный тип `QGroupBox *` к не скалярному типу `QGroupBox`.

Так что определитесь, какой тип возвращаемого значения должен быть у функции.

Обратите внимание, что в примере из документации, на который вы ссылаетесь, даннная функция имеет тип возвращаемого значения `QGroupBox *`.